# Evaluate a string with a switch in C++

Tags: c++

I want to evaluate a string with a switch but when I read the string entered by the user throws me the following error.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main() {
        string a;
        cin>>a;
        switch (string(a)) {
        case "Option 1":
            cout<<"It pressed number 1"<<endl;
            break;
        case "Option 2":
            cout<<"It pressed number 2"<<endl;
            break;
        case "Option 3":
            cout<<"It pressed number 3"<<endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"She put no choice"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

> error: invalid cast from type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to type 'int

Comment: `std::string` doesn't work with switch well.

Comment: Switch expressions must evaluate to an integral type.

Comment: [hash the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535284/how-can-i-hash-a-string-to-an-int-using-c) if you really want. [Some hashing algorithm](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html). Or could you just get the option number, i.e., 1, 2, 3, ...?

Comment: `if (a >= "Option 1" && a <= "Option 3") {std::cout << "It pressed number " + std::string(a.rbegin(), a.rbegin() + 1) << '\n';} else {std::cout << "She put no choice\n";}`

Comment: is it possible to switch on the 7th character, and surround with try/catch to test for UB in case the string does not have 7 characters ?

Comment: @antitrust: No, again, `try/catch` won't protect from UB. You need to test the length with an `if` before accessing the character. Or were you thinking of the bounds-checked `at()` method rather than the unchecked `operator[]()`?

Comment: @syam it seems to work with `at()` according to your comment and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/ so i will post my solution. thanks!

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e62ff41637776b9 (see main for usage)

Comment: A switch is basically a strongly typed if/elseif for int-checks. There's no reason for its use to ever be a _requirement_ if someone gives you flak for it. That being said, I wish there was sugar that basically allowed you to write switches using non-ints that the compiler converted into if/elseif checks. The readability is my preference for less verbose operations that have many optional triggers.

Answer (score 95):

As said before, switch can be used only with integer values. So, you just need to convert your "case" values to integer. You can achieve it by using [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) from c++11, thus some calls of constexpr functions can be calculated in compile time.

something like that...

```
switch (str2int(s))
{
  case str2int("Value1"):
    break;
  case str2int("Value2"):
    break;
}
```

where str2int is like (implementation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111667/compile-time-string-hashing)):

```
constexpr unsigned int str2int(const char* str, int h = 0)
{
    return !str[h] ? 5381 : (str2int(str, h+1) * 33) ^ str[h];
}
```

Another example, the next function can be calculated in compile time:

```
constexpr int factorial(int n)
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n-1));
}  

int f5{factorial(5)};
// Compiler will run factorial(5) 
// and f5 will be initialized by this value. 
// so programm instead of wasting time for running function, 
// just will put the precalculated constant to f5
```

Comment: The compiler might do so, or might not. If you made `f5` `constexpr`, it would have to.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why i hate working with c++. It violates the principle of least surprise in so many ways. This is one of them.

Comment: Excellent! Very helpful

Comment: I like the technique, but I don't necessarily like the functions chosen since `str2int(s)` is going to have to be calculated at runtime.  For strings in particular, a FNV hash is extremely fast to calculate at runtime and a constexpr version is available on google for generating the switch constants.

Comment: Be careful using only the hash to test for string equality. For example, with this `str2int()` function, `str2int("WS") == str2int("tP")` and `str2int("5g") == str2int("sa")`.  See http://dmytry.blogspot.com/2009/11/horrible-hashes.html  As unlikely as a hash collision among the strings you're actually comparing might be, in my opinion it's better to use a lookup table that converts strings to an enum (as suggested by in mskfisher's answer).

Comment: `str2int(s)` should be `str2int(s.c_str())` if s is a std::string. A good solution would be to make another `str2int` function that accept `std::string`s but isn't constexpr

Comment: nice to see djb hash + constexpr. but there might be a collision and error shown will be very misleading.

Comment: Your HASH function is not the same that what I can see if I follow your link HERE !ndeed, in your hash function you use a ^ operator to make an XOR of INT but in HERE, it is a + operator for 2 or 3 answers and a ^ operator for only one !!! What is correct HASH algorithm to use ?

Comment: @schlebe Yes I see, Honestly I cannot say which Hash function is better, the purpose of this answer was to show how to use `constexpr` for the question. In any case compiler will emit an error if this hash function gives the same result for different strings in `switch` block.

Comment: @Serhiy: for your information, Dan Bernstein seems to be author of this algorithm and he has defined his algorithm using first + operator and in second time ^ operator. I have found some information there: www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html. But it is a good thing that compiler verify that   possible values are all distincts. The only disturbing issue is that value to evaluated can be equal to hash value without being equal to String !!!

Answer (score 37):

You can map the strings to enum values, then switch on the enum:

```
enum Options {
    Option_Invalid,
    Option1,
    Option2,
    //others...
};

Options resolveOption(string input);

//  ...later...

switch( resolveOption(input) )
{
    case Option1: {
        //...
        break;
    }
    case Option2: {
        //...
        break;
    }
    // handles Option_Invalid and any other missing/unmapped cases
    default: {
        //...
        break;
    }
}
```

Resolving the enum can be implemented as a series of `if` checks:

```
 Options resolveOption(std::string input) {
    if( input == "option1" ) return Option1;
    if( input == "option2" ) return Option2;
    //...
    return Option_Invalid;
 }
```

Or a map lookup:

```
 Options resolveOption(std::string input) {
    static const std::map<std::string, Option> optionStrings {
        { "option1", Option1 },
        { "option2", Option2 },
        //...
    };

    auto itr = optionStrings.find(input);
    if( itr != optionStrings.end() ) {
        return itr->second;
    }
    return Option_Invalid; 
}
```

Comment: Is resolveOption another function or is that something in the standard library?

Comment: resolveOption is the custom function that calculates the value of the enumerator Options based on the current program input,

Comment: For clarity, I've added two possible implementations of a `resolveOption()` function.

Comment: Finally, with this solution, it seems really faster to replace the switch by a if/else statement. In fact, you do that in the first version of the function resolveOption.

Comment: Agreed.  The switch on enum is faster (a single integer comparison) but the conversion overhead only makes sense if you need to do the comparison over and over.

Comment: For the map lookup I think it should be return itr->second;

Comment: Thanks, @coincoin - fixed.

Answer (score 19):

A `switch` statement can only be used for integral values, not for values of user-defined type. (And even if it could, your input operation doesn't work, either. The `>>` operation extracts single tokens, separated by whitespace, so it can never retrieve a value `"Option 1"`.)

You might want this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


std::string input;

if (!std::getline(std::cin, input)) { /* error, abort! */ }

if (input == "Option 1")
{
    // ... 
}
else if (input == "Option 2")
{ 
   // ...
}

// etc.
```

Answer (score 16):

You can only use switch-case on types castable to an int.

You could, however, define a `std::map<std::string, std::function> dispatcher` and use it like `dispatcher[str]()` to achieve same effect.

Comment: You need to make sure a function exists in the map, otherwise [a default-constructed `std::function` will throw `bad_function_call`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7527115/44390).  
You can validate the function is initialized with a simple bool check, like  
`auto &fn = dispatcher[str];  if( fn ) { fn(); }`

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Full stop.

`switch` is only for integral types, if you want to branch depending on a string you need to use `if/else`.

Answer (score 3):

what about just have the option number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    int op;

    cin >> s >> op;
    switch (op) {
    case 1: break;
    case 2: break;
    default:
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch value must have an Integral type. Also, since you know that differenciating character is in position `7`, you could switch on `a.at(7)`. But you are not sure the user entered 8 characters. He may as well have done some typing mistake. So you are to surround your switch statement within a Try Catch. Something with this flavour

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string a;
    cin>>a;

    try
    {
    switch (a.at(7)) {
    case '1':
        cout<<"It pressed number 1"<<endl;
        break;
    case '2':
        cout<<"It pressed number 2"<<endl;
        break;
    case '3':
        cout<<"It pressed number 3"<<endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"She put no choice"<<endl;
        break;
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The default clause in switch statement captures cases when users input is at least 8 characters, but not in {1,2,3}.

Alternatively, you can switch on values in an `enum`.

*EDIT*

Fetching 7th character with `operator[]()` does not perform bounds check, so that behavior would be undefined. we use `at()` from `std::string`, which is bounds-checked, [as explained here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/)