# Make a list of private variables changeable through a public function in C++

Tags: c++, private-members, public-method

I have about 20 private bools within a class in C++.
I would like for these to be publicly accessible using a (public) function.

Is it possible to pass the name of a (private) variable as an argument to such a function?
For example,

```
void setTrue(std::string varName)
{
    someFunctionToConvertStringToVariable = true;
}
```

Alternatively, I think that

```
void setTrue(std::string varName)
{
    if (varName == "boolA")
    {
        boolA = true;
    }
    else if (varName == "boolB")
    {
        boolB = true;
    }
}
```

would work, and could use a `switch(varName)` to reduce the number of LOC needed.

Another option would presumably be to just make all of the booleans public, and then access them using `myClass.boolA = true;` from the calling program - I'm not sure this is the best idea,  but it's certainly simpler, and so that's an argument in its favour.

Is there a generally accepted/best way to do this type of thing? Have I just set up the problem badly and is there a much smarter way to go about this? Perhaps an `enum` of varnames would allow passed variables to be checked, but I don't think that would necessarily make it easier to set the boolean.

Comment: Instead of 20 private variables you can have an array of 20, and pass index to change in public member function.

Comment: Having 20 private `bool`s in a single class is a massive design smell - it means your class is badly designed and the way you are trying to model whatever problem you're solving needs to be rethought.

Comment: Probably true, but they're for some 10k lines of code, and the bools govern in a `if(boolA) cout<< "silly description of whats happening now";` kind of way. The length of a log file varies on multiple orders of magnitude depending on which bools are set, and so if I only want to find out what's wrong with one part, setting most to false is helpful.

Comment: Making them changeable from a calling program is more helpful for other users though, who don't want to have to recompile a library over and over, or (more importantly) who want to change the value mid program, running in a loop of delta time periods (ie, program breaks at t=30s, don't spam log for first 29s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `std::map<std::string, bool>` to store the `bool` values. Then,

```
void setTrue(std::string varName)
{
    // Add some checks to make sure that varName is valid.

    varNames[varName] = true;
}
```

Comment: Going to try this - suspect it will be the answer I need though

Comment: The check if varname is valid is by checking the return value of `map::find (key)` instead of using the random access... if it is equal to `map::end` it was not valid.

Comment: Right answer, but please change the `std::string` to a const ref as well as using `find`.

Comment: As others pointed too, `std::map::operator []` shouldn't be used over here, since if `varName` is not present it will add it into `varNames` and that's not the point, use `std::map::find`

Comment: This is certainly the answer I asked for, so marked it accepted. It may be having looked into this, that my question was not desperately well posed, but this gives me something to look into/work on. Thanks

Comment: Note that you could use a map of `bool*` if you want to keep the original member list for convenience inside the class.

Comment: @chrisb2244 the objections are that you could create new map entries by passing in strings you weren't expecting; and if you don't want that behaviour then the solution is to create all the named map entries in your constructor, and use `map::find` instead of `map::operator[]`.

Comment: @Keith - Thanks, this is helpful - I was working on trying to get pointers in the right place to do that, but now it was simple with your tip.
@MattMcNabb - Also thanks, will place that inside my function. It's now looking pretty messy, but at least the implementation is encapsulated away from the user - `*(object.myMap["myName"]) = true/false;` and so on. Will make it `...myMap.find("myName")`

Answer (score 2):

If the list of these variables isn't going to change, I can propose you to use enumeration and overriden subscript operator:

```
enum MyBools
{
    First = 0,      
    BoolA = First,       
    BoolB,       
    //...
    Bool20,     
    Last = Bool20,
}    

class MyIndexedBools
{
private:
    bool m_Bools[MyBools::Last + 1];

public:
    bool& operator[] (MyBools index);
};

bool& operator[] (MyBools index);
{
    if (index < First || index > Last)
         throw "error";

    return m_Bools[index];
}
```

It is not extensible in runtime but will give you better compile-time safety than maps.

Comment: An enum is one way indeed. In C++11, you could precise you want the enum to have `size_t` as the backing storage so that no conversion is needed when converting to an index... and also because with an unsigned storage `First` becomes unnecessary. The next step would be to use `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution is the way to go here, however I think that the **switch case does not reduce the LOC**, *beside the fact that [it won't work with an `std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388510/evaluate-a-string-with-a-switch-in-c)*!

```
void setTrue(const std::string& varName)
{
    if (varName == "boolA")
    {
        boolA = true;
    }
    else if (varName == "boolB")
    {
        boolB = true;
    }
}
```

VS:

```
void setTrue(const std::string& varName)
{
    switch(str2int (varName))
    {
    case str2int ("boolA"):
        boolA = true;
        break;
    case str2int("boolB"):
        boolB = true;
        break;
    default: 
        assert (false);
    }
}
```

And keep in mind that if you do not want to modify the passed parameter it is good practice to pass it as `const`! In that case I'd personally pass it as `const` reference.

Comment: You missed copying `str2int` implementation from above link

Comment: I am not here to duplicate code, it was just to give an idea of the LOC.... I did link the original question, so feel free to take it from there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Twenty `bool` is a lot, indeed.

Instead, I would advise using a [`bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) indexed with constants (using `enum` for example). Assuming C++11:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    enum class Flag: size_t {
        Flag1,
        Flag2,
        Flag3,
        ...,
        Flag20
    };

    bool get_flag(Flag f) const { return _flags.test(size_t(f)); }

    void set_flag(Flag f, bool value) { _flags.set(size_t(f), value); }

private:
    std::bitset<size_t(Flag20) + 1> _flags;
}; // class SomeClass
```

*Note: all out of range accesses are carried out by `bitset`, handy isn't it ?*