# Does using "else if" eliminate the need for breaks after each condition in a while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

Does using "else if" eliminate the need for breaks after each condition in a while loop? I want to exit out of the loop when one of the correct inputs has been entered.

The first version of my code looked like this

```
string s;
string str;
while (true) {
        cin >> s;
        if (s == "a") {
             str = "Apple";
             break;
        }
        if (s == "b") {
             str = "Banana";
             break;
        }
        ... more ifs ...
        else {
            cout << "Did not recognize input." << endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Can I change it to the code below without negative consequence? It's much shorter and nicer-looking to me.

```
string s;
string str;
while (true) {
        cin >> s;
        if (s == "a") str = "Apple";
        else if (s == "b") str = "Banana";
        else if (s == "c") str = "Cat";
        ... more else-ifs ...
        else {
            cout << "Did not recognize input." << endl;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: If all the conditions are testing `s` for a single character string, it would be simpler, more maintainable, and more efficient to use `switch(s[0])` - or make `s` a `char` and then `switch(s)`.  Even simpler perhaps would be to use a `std::map<char, std::string>` or `std::map<std::string, std::string>` to associate the `s` key with `str` strings. directly.

Comment: Stylistically, I prefer the first one. A break at loop-scope looks plain wrong, since it defeats the purpose of the loop. Also: you need to test for `std::cin` in case of errors (`while (std::cin >> s)` is fine), and if you feel you are having too many branches, building a `std::map<string, string>` beforehand as a lookup table will get you out of this mess. Also, a specific function doing the one-line parsing, returning a boolean as a success flag will likely be more readable.

Comment: @AlexandreC. A `break` at loop scope is *intended* to 'defeat the purpose of the loop'. Language features are what they are. Don't invent extra rules.

Comment: @EJP: I don't get your point. When I see `while`, I expect a `break` statement to be a "special case", therefore inside a condition. This is a matter of taste, but when you read code, you expect to be surprised the least possible.

Comment: @Clifford the real code is a little more complicated, and not testing for single characters. I was trying to make the example as simple as possible. I am aware of switch statements but not sure when to use them over multiple ifs. Also, I will look into maps, they seem to be very useful for what I am trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will work. The `else if` chain ensures that only the `else` case `continue`s the loop, and not hitting the `else` case triggers a `break`.

Comment: Is one style more generally accepted than the other?

Comment: @user5759490: I'd find the single `break` and `continue` approach slightly more readable and slightly less error prone (no need to check each case for a `break`/`continue`). But Clifford's comment on the question offers even better options; a `switch` if they're all single character strings, or a `std::map` for lookup if not, would both be more performant, simpler and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Tip: if you want to be sure if a refactoring works you can write a test which checks if the code is correct.

Comment: Then one should run the test on the compiler/machine setup.

Answer (score 1):

The code does the same thing, and regarding the execution time there is no difference, so they are similar. You don't need the last `break` though, in the first code snippet. However, if your thinking about a good styling for your case you should take into consideration the `switch` statement.

```
while(true){
   char c;
   cin >>c;

   switch (c) {
     case 'A': 
        // deal with char A
        break;
     case 'b':
        // deal with char b
        break;
     default:
        continue;
   }
     break;
}
```

For switch statements with strings you can check this: [Evaluate a string with a switch in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388510/evaluate-a-string-with-a-switch-in-c)

I find switch statements more elegant.

Comment: But then it will loop indefinitely, won't it?

Comment: Oops, I was thinking about the second version. I agree, it shouldn't have been added to the first version.

Comment: I was on the first :P

Comment: A `switch` statement cannot be used to check string values.

Comment: Indeed. I was thinking about chars. Oh well. However this example shows us how to do it with strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388510/evaluate-a-string-with-a-switch-in-c

Comment: You realize that the `break`s in the `switch` only `break` out of the `switch`, right, not the `while`? This is an infinite loop as written, you'd need to add another `break` after the `switch`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wanted more to point out the use of the switch statement.