# C++: cast array/vector integer element to constexpr

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constexpr

I couldn't really find a solution online anywhere for this. I am a bit of a dinosaur from before C++11 and I couldn't figure out typecasting a `constexpr`.

Does anyone know how to convert a C-style array and/or a `std::vector` (integer) element into a `constexpr`?

That is to say, let's say

```
int a[]={1,2};
vector<int> v={1,2};
```

how would I convert `a[1]` and `v[1]` into `constexpr`?

```
constexpr int b=a[1];
```

for example, a compiler would complain in a for loop.

> ```
> error: the value of ‘a’ is not usable in a constant expression
>      constexpr int b=a[i];
> ```

I am pretty much out of ideas for the time being. Thanks

Comment: You can't.  Only [constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) can be assigned to a `constexpr` variable.

Comment: you'd need a timemachine to turn a value that is only known at runtime into one that is already known at compile-time

Comment: You can't , please look in cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr )
"A constexpr variable must satisfy the following requirements:

 its type must be a LiteralType.
 it must be immediately initialized
 the full-expression of its initialization, including all implicit conversions, constructors calls, etc, must be a constant expression "

Comment: AdabH, I just did. Wow.. things have changed a lot since 2017...

Comment: Can you please tell us what problem you are trying to solve by converting a dynamic value to constexpr?

Comment: I am intending to use a switch case and create a a constexpr for each case similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388510/evaluate-a-string-with-a-switch-in-c/16388594

except in my case, I want to use integers instead of strings for each case.

Comment: I don't see anything similar there... no `constexpr` for sure. Why do you need `constexpr` for your switch?

Comment: @Kit.  I am referring to:

constexpr unsigned int str2int(const char* str, int h = 0)
{
    return !str[h] ? 5381 : (str2int(str, h+1) * 33) ^ str[h];
}

switch (str2int(s))
{
  case str2int("Value1"):
    break;
  case str2int("Value2"):
    break;
}

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/nq1aar). What's your problem, again?

Comment: @Kit. ,I was able to modify it such that

constexpr unsigned int str2int(const char* str, int h = 0) { return !str[h] ? 5381 : (str2int(str, h+1) * 33) ^ str[h]; }

can take an array or vector of strings and used the str2int to set the case. This worked, but not when I switched integers.

Comment: [Still works](https://godbolt.org/z/bEbjYK). Can you update your question with the example of code that works and the example of code that doesn't? Otherwise it's completely unknown what you are trying to achieve, as I hope you already understand that you cannot use case labels with values that aren't known to the compiler at compile time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220106/discussion-between-sj-l-and-kit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion: if you can use at least C++14, instead of `std::vector`, if you can,
use a `std::array`

Declaring it `constexpr`

```
#include <array>

int main () 
 {
   constexpr std::array<int, 2u> a {1, 2};

   constexpr auto b = a[1];
 }
```

`std::array` is a type compatible with `constexpr` and so it's `operator[]()` (`const` version), or also it's `at()` method (`const` version).

C++14 is required because in C++11 `std::array::operator[]() const` and `std::array::at() const` aren't `constexpr` methods so can't be used in a constant expression.

Unfortunately, `std::vector` require memory allocation so isn't compatible (before C++20) with `constexpr`.

For the C-style array case, you have only to declare it `constexpr`

```
int main () 
 {
// VVVVVVVVV   
   constexpr int a[] = {1,2};

   constexpr auto b = a[1];
 }
```

Comment: @idclev463035818 - Why not? Done.

Comment: Okay, that looks quite promising. Is there a way to generalize to a[i], or does the index have to be well defined?

Comment: @SjL - Obviously the index has to be a constant expression too; so `constexpr auto index = 0u; constexpr auto b = a[index];` works, `auto index = 0u; constexpr auto b = a[index];` doesn't.

Comment: I see, do you have a suggestion on how to approach this if I want iterate this in a for loop?

Comment: @SjL - If you just know the use of variadic templates... I usually pass through an helper function that accept a `std::index_sequence` (that contain indexes as template values, so a sequence of constant expressions) and calling it using `std::make_index_sequence` (that generate the template sequence of indexes).

Answer (score 0):

The `constexpr` must have a constant expression, i.e. they must be known at compile time. You can't perform an assignment to `b` with `a`, it's an error in this case.

In the given code snippet, the `a` isn't defined as `constexpr`, thus, it doesn't explicitly tells the compiler that the expression is a constant.

Comment: But `a` is "known at compile time", or rather we know what it holds, at compile time. Please explain to OP why this is not enough.