# How to use strings with switch

Tags: c++, linux, macos

I am brand new to programming. I have only learned up to functions in c++ so far, so please answer with in the scope of my knowledge.

I am working of a bank account program and I want to use a switch to get the user to input whether they want to deposit or withdraw.

I know I can use an int or even a char and do some like “D” for deposit but that’s not what I want to do.

I want to able to use the whole string “deposit” with the switch statement.

Thank you!

Comment: Short answer: You can't, only integer numeric values are allowed to use with a `switch` (note: a single `char` also is a numeric value). Use an `if() {} else if() {} else {}` cascade instead.

Answer (score 1):

The switch statement in c++ only supports integer types or values that can be evaluated to an integer. At best you could write a function to evaluate your strings to an integer as mentioned here
**ref: [Evaluate a string with a switch in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388510/evaluate-a-string-with-a-switch-in-c/16388594)**