# usage of constexpr variable as a case label

Tags: c++, switch-statement, c++17, constexpr

Is it correct to use constexpr variable as a case label.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr int x = 5;

    int y = 4;

    switch (y) {
        case x - 1:
            std::cout << "case " << x << std::endl;

            break;

        case 20:
            std::cout << "case 20" << std::endl;

            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "case default" << std::endl;

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Why it would not be correct?

Comment: It is "correct" in that it is allowed by the C++ standard, just as `case 4 - 1:` is allowed.  Probably will cause confusion to whoever has to maintain that code.

Comment: Have you tried it? With multiple compilers? [The compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) is a good platform for experiments like that. If all the major compilers agree, then it it can probably be trusted.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the code here doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @Eljay Not necessarily confusion, there are cases you even cannot do otherwise. Or how would you want to handle the result of a `WaitForMultipleObjects` or `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` call (well, they have `#define`s, as C, but still...)? Admitted, posix has far superior interface with `poll`, but that's how the world is on Windows ;)

Comment: A very nice use case of this is to do switch/case for string constants as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16388610/11993121).

Comment: As example of confusion, there is the display of  `x` for the `case x-1` ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) says the case value must be

> a constant expression of the same type as the type of condition after conversions and integral promotions

That includes `constexpr` expressions like a `constexpr` variable to which you subtract 1 like in your example.

In the standard, that's [`[stmt.switch]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.switch#2):

> Any statement within the switch statement can be labeled with one or more case labels as follows:
> `case constant-expression :`
> where the constant-expression shall be a converted constant expression of the adjusted type of the switch condition.
> No two of the case constants in the same switch shall have the same value after conversion.

And a constant expression is anything in [`[expr.const]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const).

For example, you can even use a `constexpr` function call:

```
constexpr int caseLabel() {
    return 4;
}
// ...
switch (y) {
    case caseLabel():
```